# Signed APK is automatically created when cleaning the Project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.0. I have no issues in the project. Project compiles successfully and runs with no issues.

> But problem is when i try to **clean my project**, it **automatically
>   generates signed APK**. No matter how many times i clean, it always
>   generates a signed APK. I'm not aware how does this happen. And
>   **also** when i click on any options under **build** it automatically generates the Signed APK.

But previously i'm using the 1.3 android studio version. where everything works fine.

Is this the bug in IDE or some settings needs to be configured. Any help appreciated.

Edited : Added the Gradle info

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.com"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.5"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors
            {
            }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Could you post your build.gradle, probably it has some flavors or configuration to generate the signed apk.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It's not a bug. your build variant is set to release, so you have to set it back to debug mode like the image below

Access build variants option from bottom left side of the screen in Android studio.

Comment: Think your build.gradle have some signing configs included. check or share it here.

Comment: Try this, click app dropdown before run (play) icon ->select edit configuration->app->Before launch:gradle-aware make ->should contain only gradle-aware-make.

Comment: it contain only gradle aware make.

Comment: The recent update for 1.5.0 is 1.5.1 update, your android studio check once, Think it's a bug.